# Changing the background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you tell me what I have to change here to be able to change the `background-image` via Javascript?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('p').css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');
});
```

```css
.p {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 25%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    background-image: url("misc/bilder/1.png");    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    Some text
</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: CSS selector should be just `p` unless an `class="p"` is added to the paragraph.

Comment: changing background working...remove dot in css selector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css you're referencing .p which is a class but in your javascript you're referencing p which is the element. This might help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.p').css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');
});
```

Updated:
Question was updated after my answer. Remove the . from .p in css. like so:

css:

```
p {
    //some css
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('p').css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');
});
```

html:

```
<p>
 some text
</p>
```

Comment: hi could you tell me how to add an delay aswell? thanks!

Comment: `$('p').delay(500).css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');` - Just increase the number for a longer delay :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2vgMmm5G doesnt work for me could you tell me what i did wrong? ty!

Comment: Your delay is too short to notice it, try setting the delay to `.delay(2000)`, you should see a slight delay, keep increasing the number until you're happy with the results. Or you can set the delay to slow `.delay("slow")` which should have the same effect.

Comment: yeah i even testet 5000 and it instant jumped to the last pic and 35ms was because it was an animation 35ms ~ 30fps

Comment: @barney-stinson Could you create a demo example so I can try and debug it for you?

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector should be just `p` unless an `class="p"` is added to the paragraph `<p>`.

`.p` - will select paragraphs(`<p>`) `with class="p"`. `.` is classname selector. Read more about [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').css('background-image', 'url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdlyZm.png")');
});
```

```css
p {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  background-image: url("misc/bilder/1.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Some text
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class selector as shown below:

```
$('p').css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');
//^--- missign . here..
```

Current your selector `$('p')` selecting all paragraphs from your page. Instead it should select all elements having `p` class.

Your selector should be `$('.p')` like shown below:

```
$('.p').css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.p').css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/2.png")');
});
```

```css
.p {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  background-image: url("misc/bilder/1.png");    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="p">Lorem ipsum</p>
```